# Android - Start Job right away

Tags: android, android-service, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

I'm trying to use the Job Service from Android, and I'm having problems. I scheduled a job, and set it periodic for 10 minutes (600000 ms).
Is there a way to start the job right away, run it, and then wait for the 10 minutes lapse?

The code below is what I have so far, but the job starts after the 10 minutes lapse, and then every 10 minutes.

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) this.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
ComponentName mServiceComponent2 = new ComponentName(this, GPSService.class);
JobInfo.Builder builder1 = new JobInfo.Builder(1, mServiceComponent2);
builder1.setPeriodic(600000);
jobScheduler.schedule(builder1.build());
```

This code is inside a class that extends from GcmListenerService (when recives a notification, has to turn on the service).

Also, I tried to start 2 independent jobs, one with no periodic, and one with periodic set. But it also didnt work.

Thanks!